# Reader not showing any data on search?

Tags: c#, sql

I n this sample of code when the execution get there on the while(reader.read()) part.. it not enters the loop and shows there is not any data for this query. I have tried the commented things in it.. that too doesn't worked out. suggest me what's wrong in this code?

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =" + " '" + "@TableName" + "'", connection);
    // SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ActivityIndex';
    command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = listSelectTable.Text;

    //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //command.Connection = connection;
    //command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT [column_name] FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{0}'", listSelectTable.Text);


    /*using (command)
    {*/
        listSelectColumn.Items.Clear();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listSelectColumn.Items.Add((string)reader["COLUMN_NAME"]);
            }
            listSelectColumn.Items.Add("ALL");
        }
    /*}*/
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have even tried if(reader.read()) in place of while that too doesn't showed anythng :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                 WHERE TABLE_NAME =@TableName", connection);
```

There is no need to add quotes in your query, since you are specifying that in command parameters. Also, no need to use your commented code since you are aleady specifying `Connection' & 'CommandType` is Text by default.

Comment: that's not even a valid sql statement.. i tried that too.. you can check it in sql server it not works :/

Comment: am sorry that worked.. but i tried it earlier.. earlier it was nt working.. anyway thnkss :D

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameter separately no need to decorate.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@TableName", connection);            
            command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = listSelectTable.Text;


                listSelectColumn.Items.Clear();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        listSelectColumn.Items.Add((string)reader["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                    }
                    listSelectColumn.Items.Add("ALL");
                }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: that's not even a valid sql statement.. i tried that too.. you can check it in sql server it not works :/

Comment: Do you get any exception? When you run query in SSMS then whay happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code as follows

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName" , connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
command.Parameters["@TableName"].Value = listSelectTable.Text;
```